# Parallelizing do loop with MPI?

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, fortran90

I want to convert the following program to a MPI program:

```
program pi

implicit none

integer, parameter :: DARTS = 50000, ROUNDS = 10, MASTER = 0

double precision :: pi_est
double precision :: homepi, avepi, pirecv, pisum
integer :: rank
integer :: i, n
integer, allocatable :: seed(:)

! we set it to zero in the sequential run
rank = 0

! initialize the random number generator
! we make sure the seed is different for each task
call random_seed()
call random_seed(size = n)
allocate(seed(n))
seed = 12 + rank*11
call random_seed(put=seed(1:n))
deallocate(seed)

avepi = 0
do i = 0, ROUNDS-1
   pi_est = dboard(DARTS)
   ! calculate the average value of pi over all iterations
   avepi = ((avepi*i) + pi_est)/(i + 1)
end do

   print *, "Pi is ", avepi

contains

   double precision function dboard(darts)

      integer, intent(in) :: darts

      double precision :: x_coord, y_coord
      integer :: score, n

      score = 0
      do n = 1, darts
         call random_number(x_coord)
         call random_number(y_coord)

         if ((x_coord**2 + y_coord**2) <= 1.0d0) then
            score = score + 1
         end if
      end do
      dboard = 4.0d0*score/darts

   end function

end program
```

I think what I have to is to split the do loop into n parts where n is the number of processors, saving the results on a vector and then calculating the average of the vector. I'm not sure if that is correct, nor how to implement that change.

This is as far as I got right now:

A module `mpi_params.f90`

```
module mpi_params
   USE MPI
   implicit none
   integer                              :: ierr, numprocs, proc_num, &
                                           points_per_proc, istart, iend
   integer, allocatable, dimension(:)   :: displs, recvcounts 
   doubleprecision, allocatable, dimension(:)   :: proc_contrib
contains
subroutine init_mpi_params(nn)
integer, intent(in)                     :: nn
integer                                 :: i
! Determine how many points to handle with each proc
 if ( mod(nn,numprocs)==0 ) then
    points_per_proc = nn/numprocs
 else
    points_per_proc = (nn-mod(nn,numprocs))/numprocs
    if (numprocs-1 == proc_num ) points_per_proc = nn - points_per_proc*(numprocs-1)
 end if
! Determine start and end index for this proc's points
istart = proc_num * points_per_proc + 1
if (numprocs-1 == proc_num ) istart = proc_num*(nn-mod(nn,numprocs))/numprocs +1
iend = istart + points_per_proc - 1
if (numprocs-1 == proc_num ) iend = nn
ALLOCATE(proc_contrib(points_per_proc))
!print *, 'about to allocate displs' 
allocate(displs(numprocs),source=(/(i*(nn-mod(nn,numprocs))/numprocs,i=0,numprocs-1)/))
!print *, 'about to allocate recvcounts'
allocate(recvcounts(numprocs),source=(nn-mod(nn,numprocs))/numprocs)
recvcounts(numprocs)=nn - points_per_proc*(numprocs-1)
if (numprocs-1 == proc_num ) recvcounts(numprocs) = iend-istart+1
end subroutine init_mpi_params

end module mpi_params
```

and the program piMPI.f90

```
program pi
    use mpi_params
    implicit none

    integer, parameter              :: DARTS = 50000, ROUNDS = 10, MASTER = 0
    double precision                :: pi_est
    double precision                :: homepi, avepi, pirecv, pisum
    integer                         :: rank
    integer                         :: i, n
    integer, allocatable            :: seed(:)
    double precision                :: y(ROUNDS)  


    call mpi_init(ierr)
    call mpi_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr)
    call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, proc_num, ierr)
    CALL init_mpi_params(ROUNDS)

    ! we set it to zero in the sequential run
    rank = 0

    ! initialize the random number generator
    ! we make sure the seed is different for each task
    call random_seed()
    call random_seed(size = n)
    allocate(seed(n))
    seed = 12 + rank*11
    call random_seed(put=seed(1:n))
    deallocate(seed)

    avepi = 0
    do i = istart, iend
       proc_contrib(i) = dboard(DARTS)
    end do

!!! MPI Reduce?
    call MPI_ALLGATHER(proc_contrib, points_per_proc, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                       y, points_per_proc, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                       MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

     avepi = sum(y)/ROUNDS           
if (proc_num .eq. 0) then
    print *, "Pi is ", avepi
end if

    call mpi_finalize(ierr)

contains

   double precision function dboard(darts)

      integer, intent(in) :: darts

      double precision :: x_coord, y_coord
      integer :: score, n

      score = 0
      do n = 1, darts
         call random_number(x_coord)
         call random_number(y_coord)

         if ((x_coord**2 + y_coord**2) <= 1.0d0) then
            score = score + 1
         end if
      end do
      dboard = 4.0d0*score/darts

   end function

end program
```

I can compile this code with:

```
$ mpif90 mpi_params.f90 piMPI.f90
```

and run it with 1 or 2 processors with

```
$ mpiexec -n 1 ./a.out  
Pi is    3.1369359999999999     
$ mpiexec -n 2 ./a.out 
Pi is    1.5679600000000000
```

But the results seems to be wrong with n=2. Additionally, if I try to run it with 3 or more I get these errors:

```
$ mpiexec -n 3 ./a.out
Fatal error in PMPI_Allgather: Message truncated, error stack:
PMPI_Allgather(992)...............: MPI_Allgather(sbuf=0x213e9f0, scount=3, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, rbuf=0x7ffc2638df80, rcount=3, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Allgather_impl(838)..........: 
MPIR_Allgather(797)...............: 
MPIR_Allgather_intra(555).........: 
MPIDI_CH3U_Receive_data_found(131): Message from rank 2 and tag 7 truncated; 32 bytes received but buffer size is 24
Fatal error in PMPI_Allgather: Message truncated, error stack:
PMPI_Allgather(992)...............: MPI_Allgather(sbuf=0x24189f0, scount=3, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, rbuf=0x7fff89575790, rcount=3, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Allgather_impl(838)..........: 
MPIR_Allgather(797)...............: 
MPIR_Allgather_intra(532).........: 
MPIDI_CH3U_Receive_data_found(131): Message from rank 2 and tag 7 truncated; 32 bytes received but buffer size is 24

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 5990 RUNNING AT UltraPro
=   EXIT CODE: 1
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: My question has two parts. If the way I'm thinking about making the code is correct, and how to implement the change. If those are not admissible questions, I will delete it... Sorry....

Comment: @AlexanderVogt I made some changes to my question, hopefully now is more clear what my problem is

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes, I'm trying to parallelise a monte-carlo method for computing the value of pi. All the other things you said, are also correct. But, I'm not sure how to implement the solution you have in mind. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your code, and it's always possible that I haven't, then it's a straightforward Monte Carlo calculation of the value of pi with the nice characteristic, for beginner parallel programmers, that simply calculating more (random) numbers will improve the accuracy of the total estimate.  To make `M` calculations you can either have one process calculate all of them, or `P` processes calculate `M/P` of them and then take the average to get the same accuracy.  There's no need, in this approach, for any message passing to take place until the final reduction of the local values to a global value at the end of the program.

So first have each process calculate how many iterations it is to run, let each process figure this out for itself by using the program parameters, and by calling mpi routines to find out `num_procs`, etc.

I think that the outline of your code should be something like this:

```
program main
    ! all processes make same declarations, including variables to be used
    ! to calculate pi, and parameters

    call mpi_init(...)
    ...
    ! calculate pi independently on each process, no MPI calls necessary
    ! each process uses program parameters to calculate own contribution
    call mpi_reduce(local_pi, master_pi, 1, mpi_double_precision, mpi_sum, 0, &
               mpi_comm_world, ierr)
    if (proc_num==0) write(*,*) 'pi = ', master_pi/num_procs
    call mpi_finalize
```

and that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for code that can be compiled, this is my working solution:

```
program pi
    use mpi_params
    implicit none

    integer, parameter              :: DARTS = 500000, ROUNDS = 100, MASTER = 0
    double precision                :: pi_est
    double precision                :: homepi, avepi, pirecv, pisum
    integer                         :: rank
    integer                         :: i, n
    integer, allocatable            :: seed(:)
    double precision                :: y 
    double precision                :: sumpi


    call mpi_init(ierr)
    call mpi_comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ierr)
    call mpi_comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, proc_num, ierr)
    CALL init_mpi_params(ROUNDS)

    ! we set it to zero in the sequential run
    rank = 0

    ! initialize the random number generator
    ! we make sure the seed is different for each task
    call random_seed()
    call random_seed(size = n)
    allocate(seed(n))
    seed = 12 + rank*11
    call random_seed(put=seed(1:n))
    deallocate(seed)

    y=0.0d0
    do i = istart, iend
       y = y + dboard(DARTS)
    end do

    call mpi_reduce(y, sumpi, 1, mpi_double_precision, mpi_sum, 0, &
                    mpi_comm_world, ierr)


if (proc_num==0) write(*,*) 'pi = ', sumpi/ROUNDS

    call mpi_finalize(ierr)

contains

   double precision function dboard(darts)

      integer, intent(in) :: darts

      double precision :: x_coord, y_coord
      integer :: score, n

      score = 0
      do n = 1, darts
         call random_number(x_coord)
         call random_number(y_coord)

         if ((x_coord**2 + y_coord**2) <= 1.0d0) then
            score = score + 1
         end if
      end do
      dboard = 4.0d0*score/darts

   end function

end program
```

and the extra module

```
module mpi_params
   USE MPI
   implicit none
   integer                              :: ierr, numprocs, proc_num, &
                                           points_per_proc, istart, iend
   doubleprecision, allocatable, dimension(:)   :: proc_contrib
contains
subroutine init_mpi_params(nn)
integer, intent(in)                     :: nn
integer                                 :: i
! Determine how many points to handle with each proc
 if ( mod(nn,numprocs)==0 ) then
    points_per_proc = nn/numprocs
 else
    points_per_proc = (nn-mod(nn,numprocs))/numprocs
    if (numprocs-1 == proc_num ) points_per_proc = nn - points_per_proc*(numprocs-1)
 end if
! Determine start and end index for this proc's points
istart = proc_num * points_per_proc + 1
if (numprocs-1 == proc_num ) istart = proc_num*(nn-mod(nn,numprocs))/numprocs +1
iend = istart + points_per_proc - 1
if (numprocs-1 == proc_num ) iend = nn
ALLOCATE(proc_contrib(points_per_proc))
end subroutine init_mpi_params

end module mpi_params
```

This code can be compiled with

```
mpif90 mpi_params.f90 piMPI.f90
```

and runs with

```
time mpiexec -n 10 ./a.out
```

Is more complicated than the solution proposed by @HighPerformanceMark because I wanted to keep the idea of splitting the do loop (is useful for some other code i'm working on)